# Approximate the probability of “bad days”.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables, central-limit-theorem

Every day A plays $9$ games with his computer. In each game, he will win, draw or lose with probabilities $\frac{1}{2}$, $\frac{1}{3}$ and $\frac{1}{6}$ respectively. He calls a day “bad” if he wins less than $50 \%$ of the games in a day. Note that a day is a “bad day” with a probability of $\frac{1}{2}$. Approximate the probability that within $64$ days, he experienced more than $29$ “bad days”.

**My approach so far :**

Let $S_n = X_1+X_2+...+X_n$ where $X_i = 1_{\text{ ith day is "bad"}}$.

So, we need $P[S_{64} > 29]$. We can use the CLT to approximate this probability.

Here $E[X_i]=\frac{1}{2}$ and $\sigma = \frac{1}{2}$, so the probability is equivalent to $P[\frac{S_{64}-64 \times \frac{1}{2}}{4} > \frac{29}{4}] = 1-\Phi(\frac{29}{4})$ but that is very very close to $0$.

Am I going wrong somewhere with this?

Comment: Why is a day bad with probability of $1/2$? A loss is not the same as a draw.

Comment: For getting $P[\text{Bad day}]=P(1 W)+P(2 W)+P(3 W)+P(4 W)$. Now these events can again be partitioned into for example $1W, 3L, 6 D$ and sum over all possible cases. I think that in the question all those probabilities have been summed up to get $\frac{1}{2}$

Comment: Ah, I see. I was misreading/misinterpreting it as a day is bad if he has a winning percentage of less than $50\%$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you wrote for the mean and standard deviation of a single day's outcome is correct; however, your application of the central limit theorem is incorrect.

The CLT states
$$\sqrt{n} (\bar X_n - \mu) \overset{d}{\to} \operatorname{Normal}(0, \sigma^2),$$ where $\bar X_n$ is the sample mean $\frac{1}{n} \sum X_i$, and $\mu$, $\sigma$ are the mean and standard deviation of the $X_i$.  But since $S_n = n \bar X_n$, that is to say, $S_n$ is the *sample total*, we have

$$\sqrt{64} \left(\frac{S_{64}}{64} - \frac{1}{2}\right)$$ is approximately normal with mean $0$ and variance $1/4$; equivalently,
$$\frac{S_{64}}{4} - 8$$ is approximately standard normal.  We then compute *using continuity correction*
$$\Pr\left[S_{64} > 29\right] \approx \Pr\left[\frac{S_{64}}{4} - 8 > \frac{29.5}{4} - 8 \right] \approx \Pr[Z > -0.625] = 1 - \Phi(-0.625) \approx 0.734014.$$

The *exact* probability is binomial with $n = 64$ and $p = 1/2$:

$$\Pr[S_{64} > 29] = 2^{-64} \sum_{x=30}^{64} \binom{64}{x} = \frac{13537062193921960835}{18446744073709551616} \approx 0.733846,$$ which shows that the normal approximation with continuity correction performs fairly well.

As a side note, $\Pr[X_i = 1] = 1/2$ is correct.  Specifically, the probability of a "bad day" is $$\Pr[X_i = 1] = \frac{1}{2^9} \sum_{x=0}^4 \binom{9}{x} = \frac{1}{2}.$$

Comment: Oh, I get it! Thanks a lot